# Selecionar vetor apenas com datas compartilhadas por todos as matrizes da lista

Tags: r

Tenho um banco de dados com muitos ativos da bolsa de valores. Após rodar diversos filtros para obter apenas ativos com número de observações imposto, chego a um grande data frame e a um a lista, como estará exposto no código a seguir

```
# Pacotes necessários ---------------------------------------------------
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(quantmod)
library(tidyverse)

lista$SUZB3.SA

# Inputs necessários ------------------------------------------------------
#Definição do número de observações mínimo que se deseja obter
#aconselho olhar o arquivo base01, ver um número de observações máximo para o período para maioria dos ativos
nmin<-2200

#data inicial
first.date <- as.Date("2010-01-01")

#data final
last.date <- Sys.Date()

#frequencia das observações
freq.data <- 'daily'


#Tickers para o teste inicial
tickers<-c("^BVSP","^GSPC","BRL=X","ABCB4.SA","EALT3.SA","EALT4.SA","ADHM3.SA",
           "TIET3.SA","TIET4.SA","AFLT3.SA",
           "BRGE3.SA","BRGE5.SA","BRGE7.SA","BRGE8.SA","BRGE11.SA",
           "BRGE12.SA","CRIV3.SA","CRIV4.SA","RPAD3.SA","RPAD5.SA","RPAD6.SA","BRIV3.SA","BRIV4.SA","ALSC3.SA",
           "AALR3.SA","ALPA3.SA","ALPA4.SA",
           "ALUP3.SA","ALUP4.SA","BAZA3.SA","ABEV3.SA",
           "CBEE3.SA","ANIM3.SA","ARZZ3.SA","ATOM3.SA",
           "AZEV3.SA","AZEV4.SA","AZUL4.SA","BTOW3.SA","BAHI3.SA","BPAN4.SA","BGIP3.SA","BGIP4.SA","BEES3.SA",
           "BEES4.SA","BRSR3.SA","BRSR5.SA","BRSR6.SA","BDLL4.SA","BTTL3.SA",
           "BALM4.SA","BBSE3.SA","BMKS3.SA","BIOM3.SA",
           "BSEV3.SA","BOBR4.SA","BBRK3.SA","BRML3.SA",
           "BPHA3.SA","BRPR3.SA","BBDC3.SA","BBDC4.SA","BRAP3.SA","BRAP4.SA","BBAS3.SA","AGRO3.SA",
           "BRKM3.SA","BRKM5.SA","BRKM6.SA","BRFS3.SA",
           "BPAC3.SA","BPAC5.SA","CAMB4.SA","CAML3.SA",
           "CRFB3.SA","CCRO3.SA","CCXC3.SA","CEBR5.SA","CEBR6.SA","CEDO3.SA","CEDO4.SA",
           "EEEL3.SA","EEEL4.SA","CEGR3.SA","CLSC3.SA","CLSC4.SA","CELP3.SA","CELP5.SA",
           "CELP6.SA","CELP7.SA","CEPE5.SA","CEPE6.SA","RANI3.SA","RANI4.SA",
           "MAPT4.SA","CMIG3.SA","CMIG4.SA","CESP3.SA","CESP5.SA","CESP6.SA","HGTX3.SA",
           "CIEL3.SA","CEEB3.SA",
           "COCE3.SA","COCE5.SA","CGAS3.SA","CGAS5.SA",
           "CALI4.SA","CSMG3.SA","CPLE3.SA","CPLE6.SA","CORR4.SA","RLOG3.SA",
           "CSAN3.SA","CSRN3.SA","CSRN5.SA","CTNM3.SA","CTNM4.SA","CPFE3.SA","CPRE3.SA",
           "CRDE3.SA","CRPG5.SA","CRPG6.SA","CARD3.SA","CVCB3.SA","CCPR3.SA","CYRE3.SA",
           "DASA3.SA","PNVL3.SA","PNVL4.SA","DIRR3.SA","DOHL3.SA","DOHL4.SA","DMMO3.SA","DTCY3.SA",
           "DTEX3.SA","ECOR3.SA","ELEK3.SA","ELEK4.SA","EKTR4.SA","ELET3.SA",
           "ELET5.SA","ELET6.SA","LIPR3.SA","ELPL3.SA","EMAE4.SA","EMBR3.SA","ECPR3.SA",
           "ENBR3.SA","ENMT3.SA","ENMT4.SA","ENGI3.SA","ENGI4.SA","ENEV3.SA","EGIE3.SA","EQTL3.SA","ESTC3.SA",
           "ESTR4.SA","ETER3.SA","EUCA3.SA","EUCA4.SA","EVEN3.SA","BAUH4.SA","EZTC3.SA",
           "FHER3.SA","FESA3.SA","FESA4.SA",
           "FLRY3.SA","FJTA3.SA",
           "FJTA4.SA","FRAS3.SA","GFSA3.SA","GSHP3.SA",
           "GEPA3.SA","GEPA4.SA","GOAU3.SA","GOAU4.SA","GGBR3.SA","GGBR4.SA","GOLL4.SA",
           "GPCP3.SA","CGRA3.SA","CGRA4.SA","GRND3.SA","GUAR3.SA","HBTS5.SA",
           "HAGA3.SA","HAGA4.SA","HBOR3.SA","HETA4.SA",
           "HOOT4.SA","HYPE3.SA",
           "IDNT3.SA","IGBR3.SA","IGTA3.SA","PARD3.SA",
           "MEAL3.SA","ROMI3.SA","IDVL3.SA","IDVL4.SA",
           "INEP3.SA","INEP4.SA","MYPK3.SA","IRBR3.SA",
           "ITSA3.SA","ITSA4.SA","ITUB3.SA","ITUB4.SA","JBDU3.SA",
           "JBDU4.SA","JBSS3.SA","JHSF3.SA","JFEN3.SA","JOPA3.SA","JSLG3.SA",
           "CTKA3.SA","CTKA4.SA","KEPL3.SA","KLBN3.SA","KLBN4.SA","KROT3.SA",
           "LLIS3.SA","LIGT3.SA","LINX3.SA","RENT3.SA","LCAM3.SA",
           "LOGN3.SA","LAME3.SA","LAME4.SA","AMAR3.SA","LREN3.SA","LPSB3.SA",
           "LUPA3.SA","MDIA3.SA","MGLU3.SA","MAGG3.SA","MGEL4.SA","POMO3.SA","POMO4.SA",
           "MRFG3.SA","MSPA3.SA","MSPA4.SA","MEND5.SA","MEND6.SA",
           "BMEB3.SA","BMEB4.SA","MERC4.SA","BMIN3.SA","BMIN4.SA","MTIG4.SA","LEVE3.SA",
           "FRIO3.SA","MTSA3.SA","MTSA4.SA","MILS3.SA","BEEF3.SA",
           "MNPR3.SA","MMXM3.SA","MOAR3.SA","MOVI3.SA","MRSA3B.SA","MRSA5B.SA","MRSA6B.SA",
           "MRVE3.SA","MULT3.SA","MPLU3.SA","NAFG3.SA","NAFG4.SA","NATU3.SA",
           "BNBR3.SA","NORD3.SA","NUTR3.SA","ODPV3.SA","OIBR3.SA","OIBR4.SA","OMGE3.SA",
           "OSXB3.SA","OFSA3.SA","PCAR3.SA","PCAR4.SA","PATI3.SA","PATI4.SA","PEAB3.SA","PEAB4.SA",
           "PMAM3.SA","PDGR3.SA","RPMG3.SA","BRDT3.SA","PETR3.SA","PETR4.SA","PRIO3.SA","PTNT3.SA",
           "PTNT4.SA","PINE4.SA","PLAS3.SA","FRTA3.SA","PSSA3.SA","PTBL3.SA",
           "POSI3.SA","PFRM3.SA","QGEP3.SA","QUAL3.SA","RADL3.SA","RAPT3.SA",
           "RAPT4.SA","RCSL3.SA","RCSL4.SA","REDE3.SA","RNEW3.SA","RNEW4.SA","RSUL4.SA","RDNI3.SA",
           "RSID3.SA","RAIL3.SA","SBSP3.SA","SAPR3.SA","SAPR4.SA","SNSY3.SA","SNSY5.SA",
           "SANB3.SA","SANB4.SA","CTSA3.SA","CTSA4.SA","STBP3.SA","SCAR3.SA","SMTO3.SA",
           "SLED3.SA","SLED4.SA","SHUL4.SA","CSAB3.SA","CSAB4.SA",
           "SNSL3.SA","SEER3.SA","CSNA3.SA","SSBR3.SA","SLCE3.SA","SMLS3.SA","SEDU3.SA",
           "SOND6.SA","SPRI3.SA","SPRI5.SA","SGPS3.SA","AHEB3.SA",
           "SULA3.SA","SULA4.SA",
           "SUZB3.SA","TAEE3.SA","TAEE4.SA","TRPN3.SA","TECN3.SA","TCSA3.SA","TCNO3.SA","TCNO4.SA",
           "TOYB3.SA","TOYB4.SA","TGMA3.SA","TEKA4.SA","TKNO4.SA","TELB3.SA","TELB4.SA","VIVT3.SA","VIVT4.SA",
           "TEND3.SA","TESA3.SA","TXRX4.SA","TIMP3.SA","SHOW3.SA",
           "TOTS3.SA","TRPL3.SA","TRPL4.SA","LUXM4.SA","TRIS3.SA","TPIS3.SA","TUPY3.SA",
           "UGPA3.SA","UCAS3.SA","UNIP3.SA","UNIP5.SA","UNIP6.SA",
           "USIM3.SA","USIM5.SA","USIM6.SA","VALE3.SA","VLID3.SA",
           "VVAR3.SA","VIVR3.SA","VULC3.SA","DISB34.SA","WEGE3.SA",
           "MWET3.SA","MWET4.SA","WHRL3.SA","WHRL4.SA","WIZS3.SA")



# Importando ativos -------------------------------------------------------
ativos <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickers, 
                          first.date = first.date,
                          last.date = last.date, 
                          freq.data = freq.data,
                          cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                   'BGS_Cache') ) 


#Eliminar Tickers que não foram encontrados nenhum dado
base01<-as.data.frame(ativos$df.control)

#vetor vazio para receber tickers corrigidos
tickerscorrigidos<-NULL

#vetor com tickers corrigidos, contendo apenas aqueles que tem o número mínimo de observações desejado
for(i in 1:nrow(base01)){
  if(base01[i,4] >= nmin){
    tickerscorrigidos<-c(tickerscorrigidos,as.character(base01[i,1]))
  }
}

tickerscorrigidos
rm(ativos)

# Importando ativos NOVAMENTE, PORÉM AGORA SÓ OS QUE TEM NÚMERO DE OBSERVAÇÕES MÍNIMO DESEJADO --------------------------------------------
ativos <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickerscorrigidos, 
                          first.date = first.date,
                          last.date = last.date, 
                          freq.data = freq.data,
                          cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                   'BGS_Cache') )
#cabeçalho para base de dados
cabecalho<-c("abertura","máxima", "mínima", "fechamento", "volume", "ajuste", "data", "ativo")

#inserir cabecalho
colnames(ativos$df.tickers)<-cabecalho



# Contador de obsevações válidas ------------------------------------------
#transformando em data.frame
ativos<-as.data.frame(ativos$df.tickers)
#Eliminando valores faltantes na base de dados
ativos<-na.omit(ativos)

#Contar quantas observações por ativo
nobservacao<-matrix(nrow = NROW(tickerscorrigidos), ncol = 2,0)
nobservacao[,1]<-tickerscorrigidos

for(i in 1:NROW(tickerscorrigidos)){

  temp<-ativos[ativos[,8] == tickerscorrigidos[i], ]
  nobservacao[i,2]<-nrow(temp)

}

nobservacao<-nobservacao[nobservacao[,2] >= nmin, ]

tickerscorrigidos<-nobservacao[,1]


# Importando ativos NOVAMENTE 2, PORÉM AGORA SÓ OS QUE TEM NÚMERO DE OBSERVAÇÕES MÍNIMO DESEJADO --------------------------------------------
ativos <- BatchGetSymbols(tickers = tickerscorrigidos, 
                          first.date = first.date,
                          last.date = last.date, 
                          freq.data = freq.data,
                          cache.folder = file.path(tempdir(), 
                                                   'BGS_Cache') )
#inserir cabecalho
colnames(ativos$df.tickers)<-cabecalho 

#transformando em data.frame
ativos<-as.data.frame(ativos$df.tickers)

#eliminando colunas desnecessárias
ativos<-ativos[,-10:-9]

# Validação dos Dados ---------------------------------------------
#Eliminar valores NA
ativos<-na.omit(ativos)

# Cálculos ----------------------------------------------------------------

#Variação diária
#criando uma matriz para calculo da variação diária
variacao<-matrix( ncol = 1, nrow = nrow(ativos), 0)

#______________________________________________________
#calculando variação percentual diária
for(i in 1:(nrow(ativos)-1)){
  #se for o mesmo ativo, calcular a variação percentual
  if(ativos[i+1,8] == ativos[i,8]){
    variacao[i+1,1] <-  (ativos$fechamento[i+1]-ativos$fechamento[i])/ativos$fechamento[i]*100
    #se não for, calcular zero
  }else{ variacao[i+1,1] <- 0 }
}

#inserindo vetor gerado na base de dados
ativos<-cbind(ativos,variacao)
rm(variacao)

#____________________________________________________________________________

#Statuso de Sobe ou Desce

#crianto matriz para receber status
status<-matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = nrow(ativos),0)

#Inserindo variável categórica de sobe/desce
for(j in 1:nrow(ativos)){
  #se variação for positiva Sobe
  if(ativos[j,9]>0){status[j]<-"Sobe"}
  #Se variação for negativa Desce
  if(ativos[j,9]<=0){status[j]<-"Desce"}
}

#Inserindo vetor status na base de dados
ativos<-cbind(ativos,status)
#removendo objeto desnecessário
rm(status)

#___________________________________________________________________________
#variação acumulada
#vetor para variação acumulada
acumulado<-matrix( ncol = 1, nrow = nrow(ativos), 0)

#calculando variação acumulada
for(i in 1:(nrow(ativos))){
  #se for o mesmo ativo, calcular a variação percentual acumulada
  if(ativos[i+1,8] == ativos[i,8]){
    acumulado[i+1,1] <-acumulado[i,1]+ativos$variacao[i+1]
    #se não for, calcular zero
  }else{acumulado[i+1,1] <- 0 }
}

ativos<-cbind(ativos,acumulado)
rm(acumulado)

# Lista com data.frame dos ativos -----------------------------------------
#tem que colocar os ativos em lista
#função split cria uma lista separada pelo criterio de nome de ativo
lista<-split(ativos, ativos$ativo)
```

Após rodarem esse código terão o resultado descrito anteriormente. A lista de ativos é grande, mas se faz necessária para a solução do problema.

Quero agora obter um vetor onde tenho apenas as datas em que todos os ativos compartilham, ou seja, um banco de dados apenas com datas que todas as ações possuem observação .

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
# Filtro para data em que todos os ativos possuem observação --------------
data.igual<- ativos %>% count(ativos$data) %>% filter(n == 
NROW(tickerscorrigidos))

#Objeto com todas as datas comuns a todos os ativos
data.igual<-as.data.frame.Date(data.igual$`ativos$data`)
NROW(data.igual)
```

Porém não esta funcionando bem, pois é perdido mais da metade das observações, fato que não faz sentido pois há diversos filtros anteriores no código para que ao chegar nessa parte o arquivo só contenha ações com número de observações muito parecidos, onde o número foi determinado no início do código.

Percebam que se fizerem

```
NROW(data.igual)
```

o resultado será inferior a 1000, e que deveria ser superior a 2000, portanto muitas datas estão sendo eliminadas erroneamente.

**Portanto, gostaria de ajuda para chegar a um vetor que contenha apenas datas que todos as ações compartilham.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teu código está correto. Eu cheguei a outra maneira de fazer a interseção entre os dados e obtive as mesmas 841 observações que tu obteve:

```
datas.comuns <- as.Date(Reduce(intersect, lapply(lista, `[[`, "data")))
length(datas.comuns)
## 841
```

Creio que o resultado está correto, por mais que ele te pareça estranho. Se tu está duvidando da resposta, sugiro procurar manualmente as datas que *não* aparecem no vetor `data.comuns` que criei acima, e ver porque pelo menos uma ação não estão reportando nada neste dia.

Por exemplo, 18 de fevereiro de 2019 foi um dia útil, a Bovespa fechou em baixa, mas ele é um dia que não está registrado para todas as tuas ações. Como são 167 ativos, vai dar um pouco de trabalho, mas é um começo. Quem sabe assim vai ser possível para ti descobrir o que está se passando.

Comment: muito obrigado pela disponibilidade e ajuda